# cannot call web api successfully when sending xml data

Tags: c#

I cannot successfully call an API using C# at the moment.  I have attached a screen shot of the call being successfully made with Chrome PostMan although I'm not able to replicate it in C#.  He is my attempt so far which fails.  The response I get back from the server is included below.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks,
James

**Code Snippet**

```
const string xml = "<Envelope><Body> <AddRecipient>...";
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ApiUrl);
    var requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
req.Method = "POST";
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
var requestStream = req.GetRequestStream(); 
requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();  // Call API
var sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
var backstr = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
res.Close();
```

**Chrome PostMan**

[image]

**Response back from API**

```
<Envelope><Body><RESULT><SUCCESS>false</SUCCESS></RESULT><Fault><Request/><FaultCode/><FaultString>Server Error</FaultString><detail><error><errorid>50</errorid><module/><class>SP.API</class><method/></error></detail></Fault></Body></Envelope>
```

Comment: I bet you have some documentation on what error 50 means. + You are using sample xml. I don't see that in your PostMan sample.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet.  The C# attempt is using the same xml as what I'm using in PostMan.

Comment: Try calling the webservice using RestSharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any documentation about what error 50 is?  Could just be a bad pram?  If not I recommend downloading [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).  You can then properly compare the request from both PostMan and your application to see what the actual difference is.

Comment: Error code means (taken from the documentation): 50
Server Error (typically returned if the API is invoked incorrectly such as no XML passed in the request)

Comment: Like i said try Fiddler.  It could be that the API requires an extra header (such as user agent) and without it you get an error. Fiddler will show you everything about the request/response.